# John Resig Advanced Javascript Question

Tags: javascript

Im in a little over my head, but I was wondering if anyone can help me with this one:

**taken from: http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#43**

```
function highest(){ 
  return arguments.slice(1).sort(function(a,b){ 
    return b - a; 
  }); 
} 
assert(highest(1, 1, 2, 3)[0] == 3, "Get the highest value."); 
assert(highest(3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)[1] == 4, "Verify the results.");
```

**I thought it should be:**

```
Array.prototype.highest = function(){ 
  return arguments.slice(1).sort(function(a,b){ 
    return b - a; 
  }); 
} 
assert(highest(1, 1, 2, 3)[0] == 1, "Get the highest value."); 
assert(highest(3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)[1] == 1, "Verify the results.");
```

But this is giving me errors of undefined.

Comment: In the fact, wrong is reinventing Math.max

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not calling it on an array.

```
assert([].highest(1, 1, 2, 3)[0] == 1, "Get the highest value."); 
assert([].highest(3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)[1] == 1, "Verify the results.");
```

would almost work (`[]` can be any array).  However, you still didn't convert `arguments` to an array, nor did you call `slice` with [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).  That's the main point of the exercise.

Also, it doesn't make any sense, since you're not using the contents of the array.

Thus, the solution is:

```
function highest(){ 
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1).sort(function(a,b){ 
    return b - a; 
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Why are you ignoring the first parameter to `highest`?

Comment: @Crescent, that's how it is in the original tutorial.  I think it's just an example of `slice`.

Answer (score 2):

The way you're defining the function would work by adding a method to all arrays:

```
[1,2,3].highest()
```

The original function is meant to be called as a regular function:

```
highest(1,2,3)
```

Anyways, the problem with the original code has nothing to do with this. The trouble is that `arguments` is not really an array, so you need to convert it using `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` before you can call `slice` on it.

The correct answer is:

```
function highest(){
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice(1).sort(function(a,b){
    return b - a;
  });
}
```

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right! I wanted to write the same... "arguments" is not "Array", so it doesn't have method "slice"... So, conversion is needed.