# Resig Advanced Javascript p #43

Tags: javascript

having some trouble figuring out what's wrong with this. Had a look at one of the other solutions, but it was for a different version of the problem.

[John Resig Advanced Javascript Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301920/john-resig-advanced-javascript-question)

Specifically, referring to the older problem, since resig doesn't use "prototype" or "slice" at all in the tutorial prior to this problem, I'm wondering whether there's a different solution.

http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#43

here's the current text of the problem:

```
function highest(){ 
  return arguments.sort(function(a,b){ 
    return b - a; 
  }); 
} 
assert(highest(1, 1, 2, 3)[0] == 3, "Get the highest value."); 
assert(highest(3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)[1] == 4, "Verify the results.");
```

I'm also having a little trouble understanding why the "b - a" in the return. When changed to just b or just a, it still passes all tests.

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that the arguments collection is not an array? That's why you get this error: ERROR Object # has no method 'sort'.(See this for an example: http://debuggable.com/posts/turning-javascript-s-arguments-object-into-an-array:4ac50ef8-3bd0-4a2d-8c2e-535ccbdd56cb)

Comment: Also default sort behavior is lexographical i.e. an array with [7, 30, 200] is sorted as [200, 30, 7]. So you have to pass in a compare function to get a correct sort for numbers. Any specific errors that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your problem with the sort function. If you change the order of the numbers in the first assert to:

```
assert(highest(3, 1, 1, 2)[0] == 3, "Get the highest value.");
```

then doing return a or return b won't work anymore. It is just a coincidence that they work with the current asserts.

A sort function should return

- less than zero if a is ranked lower than b
- zero if they are equal
- more than zero if a is ranked higher than b

So b-a returns numbers in descending order.

If you go onto the next two pages (#44 and #45) in John Resig's tutorial you'll see that he introduces a makeArray function (http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#45) to solve the problem of turning the arguments collection into an array.